# Saving an array to parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I have a bunch of data I'm saving as one pfobject to parse and I save them in separate fields. My problem is that at the end I want to be able to search this data, access all the fields but this is very inefficient. It was suggested that I hold the fields in an array. But I don't know how to do that and I looked everywhere. How can I hold the bottom two fields PriceText and ViewsText in one array and save that array of strings. Below is the code.

```
let table = PFObject(className: "Example")
        table["Price"] = PriceText
        table["Views"] = ViewsText
        table.saveInBackground { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
            if success {

            }else{

            }
        }
         var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!
         query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
        let fiel1 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field1.whereKey("field one", contains: search)
        let field2 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field2.whereKey("field two", contains: search)
        let field3 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field3.whereKey("field three", contains: search)
        let field4 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field3.whereKey("field four", contains: search)
        let field5 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field5.whereKey("field 5", contains: search)
        let field6 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field6.whereKey("field 6", contains: search)
        let field7 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field7.whereKey("field 7", contains: search)
        let field8 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field8.whereKey("field 8", contains: search)
        let field9 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field9.whereKey("field 9", contains: search)
        let field10 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field10.whereKey("field 10", contains: search)
        let field11 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field11.whereKey("field 11", contains: search)
        let field12 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field12.whereKey("field 12", contains: search)
        let field13 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field13.whereKey("field 13", contains: search)
        let field14 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field14.whereKey("field 14", contains: search)
        let field15 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field15.whereKey("field 15", contains: search)
        let field16 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field16.whereKey("field 16", contains: search)
        let field17 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field17.whereKey("field 17", contains: search)
        let field18 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field18.whereKey("field 18", contains: search)
        let field19 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field19.whereKey("field 19", contains: search)
        let field20 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field20.whereKey("field 20", contains: search)
        let field21 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field21.whereKey("field 21", contains: search)
        let field22 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field22.whereKey("field 22", contains: search)
        let field23 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field23.whereKey("field 23", contains: search)
        let field24 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field24.whereKey("field 24", contains: search)
        let field25 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field25.whereKey("field 25", contains: search)
        let field26 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field26.whereKey("field 26", contains: search)
        let field27 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field27.whereKey("field 27", contains: search)
        let field28 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field28.whereKey("field 28", contains: search)
        let field29 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field29.whereKey("field 29", contains: search)
        let field30 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        field30.whereKey("field 30", contains: search)
        let objectId = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
        objectId.whereKey("objectId", contains: search)
        query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21, field22, field23, field24, field25, field26, field27, field28, field29, field30, objectId])
```

Comment: Why must they be in one array ?

Comment: the problem is that I have 20 other fields an I'm searching each and every one of them and I have tens of thousands of pfobjects. So someone suggested that I hold all the objects in one big array

Comment: @Mozahler This is how many fields I have and how I'm searching them. You can see. Is an array the best way to do it in your opinion.

Comment: It's Saturday night and I'm beat. However, I'll take another look tomorrow and if you don't have a good answer I'll try to come up with something. Show me the code for whereKey(_ , contains:) and orQuery. Putting two fields into an array is easy.

Comment: use a combo of BFTasks for loops and array saving, i won't show you the code because you chose to use Swft, and Swift is the stupidest language ever invented